# Can't create Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config instance in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

I am working with **Magento 2.3.** But everytime I try to create an instance of

> Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config by ObjectManager

I meet this **error**

> Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $variablePluginConfigProvider of Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\CompositeConfigProvider.

Did anyone meet and resolve this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add below code on your module frontend  di.xml file

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\CompositeConfigProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="variablePluginConfigProvider" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Variable\Model\Variable\ConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="widgetPluginConfigProvider" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\Config</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="wysiwygConfigPostProcessor" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\DefaultConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="galleryConfigProvider" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Gallery\DefaultConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>




And also change Editor call js on frontend :


             <script>
                    require([
                        'jquery',
                        'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
                    ], function (jQuery) {

                        var config = '<?php echo $block->getWysiwygConfig() ?>',
                            editor;

                        jQuery.extend(config, {
                            settings: {
                                theme_advanced_buttons1: 'bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,' +
                                'fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code',
                                theme_advanced_buttons2: null,
                                theme_advanced_buttons3: null,
                                theme_advanced_buttons4: null,
                                theme_advanced_statusbar_location: null
                            },
                            files_browser_window_url: false
                        });

                        editor = new tinyMceWysiwygSetup(
                            'short_description',
                            config
                        );

                        editor.turnOn();

                        jQuery('#short_description')
                            .addClass('wysiwyg-editor')
                            .data(
                                'wysiwygEditor',
                                editor
                            );
                    });
                </script>

           Replace: <script>
                    require([
                        "jquery",
                        "mage/translate",
                        "mage/adminhtml/events",
                        "mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup"
                    ], function(jQuery){
                        wysiwygcompany_description = new wysiwygSetup("short_description", {
                            "width":"99%",  // defined width of editor
                            "height":"200px", // height of editor
                            "plugins":[{"name":"image"}], // for image
                            "tinymce4":{"toolbar":"formatselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | link table charmap","plugins":"advlist autolink lists link charmap media noneditable table contextmenu paste code help table",
                            }
                        });
                        wysiwygcompany_description.setup("exact");
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: Worked nicely, thanks!